# unable to recover lost data after deleting mount points in ubunu

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery, storage

i have mounted two partitions on **/media** folder:

[show mount points here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQrNw.png)

so later, i could access them through GUI **as a separated partitions** like this

[show two partitions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbrwK.png)

by mistake, i have **deleted** the following mounting points of those partitions from **/media** using the command "**rm -rf ./***":

[show the deleted mountpoints in media here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovCgU.png)

when i navigated to the the partitions, there is no data on each of them, all data got lost.

i could not imagine how that happened, but i have an important information on these partitions, and i hope i can recover data.

**i want to ensure if this data still present or lost forever and if lost,
Can i recover this critical data??**

Comment: "important information" In that case you have backups. Restore the most recent one.

Comment: Unfortunately, no backups, it's a personal computer and just working for 3 months, is deleting the mountpoint means deleting everything in the device /sda3 itself?

Comment: The "r" in the command means "recursive" so everything inside and including the directory itself. You do not delete mountpoints you un-mount those. Maybe testdisk can restore it.

Answer (score 1):

The command `rm -rf ./*` will delete everything present in the current directory (`./`) that matches `*`, this means, all non-hidden files.

If you do that while in a mount point of a partition (on a drive), you are removing every visible file and directory in that partition.

After mounting, the file system of a mounted partition is an integral part of the file system. If you delete files in there, you are deleting files on the mounted partition.

So yes, the data is gone, and could be recovered only by specialist data recovery.

Sometimes we learn it the hard way, but the first lesson any computer user should take at heart is to ensure to **have good backups of your personal data**. As soon as you have that, you are good. Anything else does not matter: Operating systems can be downloaded from many places, and are reinstalled in under half an hour (except for slow systems). Personal data, however, when lost, is lost for ever.

There is one more severe warning to make: **Never** work as root user, unless you do system maintenance and know what you are doing. You deleted the contents of `/media`. That by default contains directories with user names (in your case `mma`), that in turn contain all mount points that are created when you connect a drive. These directories are owned by `root` and cannot be deleted by a normal user. So acting as root was your second very big mistake here.

If you do not have backups, your only rescue is attempting your own data recovery using `testdisk/photorec`, but do not hold your breath! More chance for more complete data recovery involves seeking (expensive) professional help.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation,  i have tried testdisk and photorec, but all returns empty partition as i can see the same in GUI., i have tried foremost but it recovers unuseful old pictures and PDFs , is there any other method that can recover all data like text files? or any other pro paid software that do that?

Comment: I am personally not aware of specific software besides photorec.